# To what extent Abel summation is stronger than Cesàro summation?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does Abel summation, like Cesàro summation, only apply to the series whose terms change their signs?

Comment: Could be complex numbers too but yes you need that (or argument variation more generally in the complex case) to get Abel summability of divergent series as Littlewood theorem says that Abel implies standard convergence if $na_n$ is bounded one sided in the real case and that is trivial if $a_n$ do not change sign indefinitely; however Abel is strictly stronger than Caesaro which is strictly stronger than convergence in general

Comment: @Conrad thanks. It seems that Borel summation is like Abel summation in this sense? I mean I need to separate summation methods that are based on some kind of "means" from those that can sum up series with term of unchanging signs/arguments (Ramanujan, Zeta regularization)

Answer (score 0):

If $a_n\geq0$ for all $n$ and $\sum_na_n=\infty$, then the series also diverges in the Abel sense.

To see this, fix $M>0$. Then there exists $m$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^ma_n>M$. This gives us
$$
\liminf_{x\to 1^-}\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n\geq\liminf_{x\to1^-}\sum_{n=1}^m a_nx^n=\sum_{n=1}^ma_n>M. 
$$
As $M$ is arbitrary, this means that $\liminf_{x\to1^-}\sum_na_nx^n=\infty$, and so $\lim_{x\to1^-}\sum_na_nx^n=\infty$.